# Sails.js custom route raises 500 forbidden for post requests

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a user controller method like:

`create: function( req, res ){
    res.json({name:"Cool Name"});
}`

But when use this

```
socket.post("/user/create", {
  myName: "John Doe"}, function(r){ console.log(r) });
```

I get an error message "Forbidden" with status code 500. Its working fine when I make normal post request. Can you please throw some light on this.

Comment: `500 forbidden` is server error, is sails throwing any exceptions? Maybe something like a route not existing? Can you post up that error please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are posting to `/user/create`, which is the "shortcut" create URL.  Shortcuts are accessed with the `GET` method (and should generally be turned off in production).  To create a user via `POST`, use the `/user` URL:

```
socket.post("/user", {myName: "John Doe"}, function(r){ console.log(r) });
```